# Can not access a public class in an assembly that has been refrenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorgenerator

Using RazoerGenerator.MSBuild I have made a MVC project that contains only one compiled view.

Using the Object Browser I can see one public class in object browser :

```
public class BootstrapTimePicker : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>
    Member of Toolbox.Common.MVC.Views
```

In another MVC website project I added Refrence to Toolbox.Common.MVC.Views project.

using Toolbox.Common.MVC.Views causes error 'Can not resolve ...'  I tried using the BootstrapTimePicker from another New/Clean project, referencing the project and again there is no access to Toolbox.Common.MVC.Views.BootstrapTimePicker

.net version of all the projects is the same 4.5

I have also tried adding the Toolbox.Common.MVC.dll to refrences but still co not access Toolbox.Common.MVC.Views.BootstrapTimePicker from any projects

Comment: You also have to reference any other DLLs your class requires, not just Common.MVC.dll.

Comment: @EddiePaz : the class has one method returning a string